# Alkaline batteries used in Ni-Cd battery rechargable power outage LED emergency light

Tags: batteries

I have a Vector Rechargeable Power Outage LED Emergency Light that plugs into the wall. When the electricity goes off, it comes on. The instructions state to use three AAA Ni-Cd batteries and I only have alkaline batteries. Hurricane Irma is headed my way and I was unable to find Ni-Cd batteries anywhere.
Is is safe for me to use alkaline batteries instead?

Comment: It's obviously unsafe to put alkaline cells in it while plugged in, as it would try to charge them.  Putting them in when not plugged in has two risks: first only the designer knows how it will react, and second you could forget that you have done so, and plug it back in with them still inside after the storm.

Answer (score 0):

Cadmium is obsolete due to toxicity for disposal.

NiCd is 1.2V/cell while Alkaline is 1.5Vcell thus 4.5V vs 3.6. Meanwhile White LED,s are around 3.1V so they have internal resistors selected to limit the current ( and brightness) and extend the duration.

Since the luminaire is obsolete due to NiCd availability, you have nothing to lose by trying it in the dark with no power.  It is safe, but the internal resistors will see a bigger power loss and get hot inside. But this is still very low power, but may fail if poorly designed.

Portable flashlights are cheap now and some come with Lipo cell charger and some using Alkaline.These much brighter than what you have.

My preference is LiPo hand torch 5W.

Answer (score 0):

Ni-Cd are rechargable batteries, and your emergency light has charger built in. You cannot put non-recharchable batteries in. It is not safe. Charger (when plugged into the wall) will eventually try to charge those batteries. It is a fire hazard to charge non-recharchable alkaline batteries.

Comment: not a hazard since the charge voltage never exceeds the cell 1.5 voltage and below at 1.2V /cell it does not conduct much power as a dead battery has high ESR.  It just wont function well or be reliable.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 it depends on type of charger. If it provides constant current, you have a problem. Or if there there's a black out, battery discharges, then power comes up, and try to charge partially discharged battery. It is not safe.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't use the charger, the light will have no clue that the batteries are of a different type. In fact, you will most likely get a longer runtime with alkalines, as they have higher mAh capacity than NiCd.

A fully charged NiCd is 1.4V, a fully charged Alkaline is 1.5V... not much of a difference.

Don't use the charger with alkaline batteries though, they could leak and ruin the lamp. They are not designed for charging.

If you still have NiCd batteries though, you should bring them to a recycling.battery disposal place because Cadmium is extremely toxic. Make sure they don't end up in a landfill. Well, you have other worries at the moment, but keep it in mind.

Stay safe ;)

Comment: Doing fine? From the other side of the atlantic, the news footage looks quite daunting...

Comment: Thank you, yes, my dog and I are fine. We just got our power on after 2 days but that pales in comparison to many! Thanks for asking!

Comment: Glad to know you're OK from the other side of the internet. Have a nice day ;)